# Select pair of records in same table SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a Access table called RECORDS with purchase records.

```
   Id   | Type |  Price  |     Date    |  Processed  |
------------------------------------------------------
   1    |  C   |   30€   |  01/01/2016 |    Null     |
------------------------------------------------------
   2    |  R   |  -30€   |  01/01/2016 |    Null     |
------------------------------------------------------
   3    |  C   |   10€   |  02/02/2016 |    Null     |
------------------------------------------------------
   4    |  C   |   10€   |  02/02/2016 |    Null     |
------------------------------------------------------
   5    |  R   |  -10€   |  02/02/2016 |    Null     |
------------------------------------------------------
   6    |  C   |   25€   |  03/02/2016 |    Null     |
------------------------------------------------------
   7    |  C   |   42€   |  04/02/2016 |    Null     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to do is to set True the charge (Type 'C') records who have an opposite pair of refund record (Type 'R').

**Like this:** 1C and 1R = True

```
   Id   | Type |  Price  |     Date    |  Processed  |
------------------------------------------------------
   1    |  C   |   30€   |  01/01/2016 |    True     |
------------------------------------------------------
   2    |  R   |  -30€   |  01/01/2016 |    True     |
------------------------------------------------------
   3    |  C   |   10€   |  02/02/2016 |    True     |
------------------------------------------------------
   4    |  C   |   10€   |  02/02/2016 |    Null     |
------------------------------------------------------
   5    |  R   |  -10€   |  02/02/2016 |    True     |
-----------------------------------------------------
   6    |  C   |   25€   |  03/02/2016 |    Null     |
------------------------------------------------------
   7    |  C   |   42€   |  04/02/2016 |    Null     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

So far I have this but it sets True all the N charge 'C' records

```
UPDATE 
RECORDS AS T1 
INNER JOIN RECORDS T2 
ON ABS(T1.Price) = ABS(T2.Price) AND T1.Date =T2.Date 
SET T1.Processed = TRUE
WHERE (T1.Type = 'C' AND T2.Type = 'R') OR (T1.Type = 'R' AND T2.Type = 'C')
```

Comment: The presence of duplicates on `Price` and `Date` is likely going to make this extremely difficult (if not impossible) with Access SQL.  Have you considered a VBA function?

Answer (score 1):

With `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE RECORDS AS T 
SET T.Processed = TRUE
WHERE 
  (T.Type IN ('C', 'R') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RECORDS 
      WHERE Type IN ('C', 'R') AND Type <> T.Type AND Date = T.Date AND Price + T.Price = 0
    )
  )
  AND T.Id = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM RECORDS WHERE Date = T.Date AND Price = T.Price AND Type = T.Type)
```

The last condition in `WHERE` covers the case of duplicates in the columns `Price`,  `Date` and `Type`.
Results:

```
Id  Type    Price   Date        Processed
1   C       30,00   1/1/2016    True
2   R       -30,00  1/1/2016    True
3   C       10,00   2/2/2016    True
4   C       10,00   2/2/2016    NULL
5   R       -10,00  2/2/2016    True
6   C       25,00   3/2/2016    NULL
7   C       42,00   4/2/2016    NULL
```

Comment: But if you add another R record with -10  on 2/2/2016 it will not mark the new line or ID 4 as true.  This only works on the first credit and first refund on the given day, that may work for the OP.  This is an FYI not criticism as it may be okay, there may never be a second refund on the same day with two charges.

Comment: Yes this is the case were only 1 pair with opposite prices at the same day will be updated. I don't know if this does not cover the requirements.